# c++ usage of delegated ctor from base class in derived class

Tags: c++, constructor, radix, derived

I'm taking a C++ class, and we're learning outdated C++ unfortunately. This question is specific and I couldn't just Google it. Thank you for answering.

How do I / can I access base privates from a derived ctor init-list? How do I / can I call a function from a derived ctor execution block?

point.h

```
class Point {
    const double x;
    const double y;
public:
    Point () = delete;
    Point ( Point && other ) : x { other.x }, y { other.y } {}
    explicit Point ( double xx, double yy) : x { xx }, y { yy }, {}
```

city.h

```
class City : public Point {
    const std::string name;
public:
    City () = delete;
    City ( City && other )
      : Point ( std::forward < City > ( other ) ) { name = other.name; }
    // is other scrapped by the time I try to get the name?
    explicit City ( double xx, double yy, std::string nname )
      : Point ( xx, yy ) { name = nname; }
```

(`explicit ctor` for ease of reference; it's the only explicit ctor I have)

In `City's explicit ctor` and `City's move ctor`, I get the same error: **no overload found for `operator=`**. Ditto with `string::assign`, and every other string method. What's going on? `string` is included.

If I stick `protected:` in front of `Point's` privates and then try to initialize them in the `explicit City ctor` initialization list `x { xx }, .. name { nname } {}`, the error says **x is not a member or base class**

Comment: `name` is `const`, you cannot assign to it. Why aren't you initializing it in the initialization list? `: Point ( xx, yy ), name ( nname ) {}`

Comment: `std::forward` doesn't buy you anything because the type of the argument is fixed. The point of `std::forward` is to reproduce exactly the type and rvalueness of the original argument, not possible when the type is fixed. Use `std::move` if the `Point` type is just an example, or better just copy and don't introduce premature non-optimizations.

Comment: For some reason, it did not occur to me that delegating a ctor occurred within the init-list. Thank you for clearing that up!

Alf, thank you for sharing that. I saw code using it between base and derived classes in a similar context, and I thought it might have something to do with delegating between base and derived. I should read before I copy paste non-optimizations.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that if `std::string name` is marked `const`, then you cannot assign to it, as `std::basic_string<>::operator=` is of course non-const. Just initialize it in the constructor list initialization like `name {other.name}`

Below is an example:

```
#include <iostream>

class Point {
    const double x;
    const double y;
public:
    Point () = delete;
    Point ( Point && other ) : x { other.x }, y { other.y } {}
    explicit Point ( double xx, double yy) : x { xx }, y { yy } {}
};
class City : public Point {
    const std::string name;
public:
    City () = delete;
    City ( City && other )
        : Point ( std::forward < City > ( other ) ) , name {other.name}{}


    // is other scrapped by the time I try to get the name?
    explicit City ( double xx, double yy, std::string nname )
        : Point ( xx, yy ), name{nname}{}
};

int main()
{
}
```